# How to add NSMutableDictionary values in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift3, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have one `NSMutableDictionary` with different keys and values. All key values I need to save in `NSMutableArray` in Swift3.

Here is my `NSMutableDictionary` :

```
  {
    92 =     (
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a09a0>",
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a0c40>"
    );
    93 =     (
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a0540>"
    );
  }
```

Note: Here 92 and 93 is my dictionary keys.

Below is my code to add dictionary all values in my array.

```
for value in videoRangeDic.allValues{

    arrVideoRange.add(value)
}
```

As an output, I am getting below array value :

```
(
        (
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a0540>"
    ),
        (
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a09a0>",
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a0c40>"
    )
)
```

Instead, I want my output should be like :

```
    (
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a0540>",
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a09a0>",
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a0c40>"
    )
```

The reason is dictionary is saving values in array like (), So I just need to remove this array. Can anyone please help me to solve my problem without creating any new array. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `arrVideoRange` is `NSMutableArray`  like this

```
var arrVideoRange : NSMutableArray = []
```

then try this

```
for value in videoRangeDic.allValues{

    arrVideoRange.addObjects(from: value as [Any])

}
```

Comment: @user2786 checkout my answer

Comment: Thanks for your response @jignesh. I tried above code but getting the array output like (
        (
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a0540>"
    ),
        (
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a09a0>",
        "<Group.VideoRange: 0x6040003a0c40>"
    )
)

Comment: can you please add arrVideoRange declaration code ?

Comment: Yes I have added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159637/discussion-between-user2786-and-jignesh-vadadoriya).

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the value of your dic by single line code

```
print("values array : \(videoRangeDic.map{$0.value}.flatMap{$0})")
```

Comment: Thank you @iPatel for your time,  I tried above solution. I'm not getting my array output in single ().

Comment: Yes because you are using objective c array and dictionary thats why

Comment: Is there any way to convert objective c array and dictionary into swift?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flatMap](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-2-flatmap/) to flatten the array of dictionaries to array

```
let array = groupDicts.flatMap { $0.values.joined() }

or

let newArray = Array(dicts.lazy.flatMap { $0.values }.joined())
```